# What purpose does the "fclose" highlighted serve?

Tags: gcc, optimization, x86

I'm disassembling some of my own code to learn more about x86 and found this interesting pattern when compiling with -Ofast under gcc. What purpose does this "fclose" function serve ? It doesn't seem to be affecting the execution of my program in any unexpected way.

[image: Disassembly of a gcc compiled binary]

Comment: uhm, nope. I know what @plt is but why are there 2 fclose and why is the "other" fclose being called after totally unrelated functions like memset/fopen/malloc etc...

Comment: It is dealing in some way with shared library functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That address you have highlighted doesn't seem to have any symbol associated with it, so the disassembler just used the nearest symbol `fclose@plt` and computed the offset from it (in this case, `0x10` bytes before `fclose@plt`). The only relevance that `fclose` actually has is that it's in memory just after the highlighted address.

If you look at all the `jmp` instructions to that address, you'll see they're labeled as `_init+0x30`, so (for whatever reason) it picked a different relative symbol.

Comment: I noticed that as well, but the question remains, what is the piece of code doing ? Also without any jmp/ret, wouldn't that function fall through to fclose anyway ?

Comment: Nope, look at line 24, there's a `jmp` instruction - basically, it'll grab the address of e.g. `fclose`, so the next time it's called, it'll jump to the actual function instead of the generic lookup. You can find much more (better) information by looking up "elf plt" or "elf got".